# I want to make the spline chart from highcharts.com smaller in size

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to minify the chart Interface. Currently I am using chart with size 600 x 300 px, which is working fine.

Now I want to show 3 charts at the same place so in order to save space. I want to show 3 charts thumbnails (working charts). If user click on any chart it should appear as full chart. I can show it on the popup or expand it on the page itself.

I checked the Highchart website. It provide option to resize chart using height & width properties.

```
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.height
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.width
```

This option do not actually resize the chart. Char layout get smaller but the title label stay at the same size. I want chart to resize and work in a smaller version with text and chart show in smaller box like 100 x 100 px.

I can use `chart.setSize();` function to resize the chart.

Does it make any sense? Please guide me.

I am using highcharts 5.0 version js file.

Here is my code:

```
 var seriesData1 = {
                    name: "Series1Label",
                    data: Series1Data
                },
                seriesData2 = {
                    "name": "Series2Label",
                    "data": Series2Data
                },
                seriesData3 = {
                    "name": "Series3Label",
                    "data": Series3Data
                },
                completedData = [seriesData2, seriesData3, seriesData1];

 var elem = par.find('<some class>');

    elem.highcharts({
                    chart: {
                        type: 'areaspline'
                    },
                    colors: ['#21d0b8', '#2248B5', '#5B82A1'], 

                    title: {
                        text: ""
                    },
                    legend: {
                        layout: 'horizontal',
                        align: 'left',
                        verticalAlign: 'top',
                        useHTML: true,
                        itemDistance: 5,
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        'title': {
                            text: xAxisTitle
                        },
                        categories: categories,
                        tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
                        title: {
                            enabled: false
                        }
                    },
                    yAxis: {

                        title: {
                            text: ''
                        }
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        shared: true
                    },
                    credits: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        series: {
                            events: {
                                legendItemClick: function(event) {


                                }
                            }
                        },
                        areaspline: {
                            fillOpacity: 0.8
                        },
                        area: {
                            fillColor: {
                                linearGradient: {
                                    x1: 0,
                                    y1: 0,
                                    x2: 0,
                                    y2: 1
                                },
                                stops: [
                                    [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                                    [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                                ]
                            },
                            marker: {
                                radius: 2
                            },
                            lineWidth: 1,
                            states: {
                                hover: {
                                    lineWidth: 1
                                }
                            },
                            threshold: null
                        }
                    },
                    series: completedData,

                    exporting: {
                        buttons: {
                            contextButton: {
                                text: 'Export',
                                useHTML: true,
                                align: 'right',
                                symbolY: 15,
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    responsive: {
                        rules: [{
                            condition: {
                                maxWidth: 100
                            },
                            chartOptions: {
                                legend: {
                                    align: 'center',
                                    verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                                    layout: 'horizontal'
                                },
                                yAxis: {
                                gridLineWidth: 0,
                                minorGridLineWidth: 0,
                                    labels: {
                                         enabled:false,
                                    },
                                    title: {
                                        text: null
                                    }
                                },
                                 xAxis: {
                                    labels: {
                                         enabled:false,
                                    },
                                    title: {
                                        text: null
                                    }
                                },
                                title:{
                                                text: '',
                                },
                                subtitle: {
                                    text: null
                                },
                                tooltip:{
                                enabled:false,
                                },
                                legend:{
                                enabled:false,
                                },
                                credits: {
                                    enabled: false
                                }
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                });
```

The 'elem' chart element occurs 7 times on a single page, so I have made a single code to fill all the charts on different data and trigger them all at single function.

I need all the 7 charts to show in thumbnail and show certain chart in large size on  user click.

using your example when I update my code.

```
var getChart = ele_.highcharts({.....});
```

Resize code:

```
getChart.setSize(100, 100);
```

Error encountered

```
getChart.setSize is not a function
```

Can anyone guide me how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check [responsive](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/responsive) and set rules accordingly.
For 100 by 100 you should remove all gridlines, credits, labels, title

Example will be

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'line',
    width: 100,
    height: 100
  },
  legend: {
    align: 'center',
    verticalAlign: 'bottom',
    layout: 'horizontal'
  },
  yAxis: {
    gridLineWidth: 0,
    minorGridLineWidth: 0,
    labels: {
      enabled: false,
    },
    title: {
      text: null
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    labels: {
      enabled: false,
    },
    title: {
      text: null
    }
  },
  title: {
    useHTML: true,
    text: ''
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: null
  },
  tooltip: {
    enabled: false,
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false,
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },

  series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
  }]
});
$('#container').highcharts().renderer.text('mini Highcharts', 20, 90)
  .css({
    fontSize: '8px',
    color: '#7d7d7d'
  })
  .add();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

check this using `chart.setSize();`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y7enqv9f/)

**Update**

You could use `$(elem).highcharts().setSize(100, 100);`

[Updated](http://jsfiddle.net/3w3eLwnp/) fiddle

Comment: Thanks for responding. Let me check it.

Comment: I have added my code and the issue I am facing. Can you please check and tell me what is missing?

Comment: I think the problem is difference in functions I am using. I am using $(elm).Highcharts({}), and you are using. var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {}). Therefore you are able to create its object where as my object isn't working or accessible to setSize() function.

Comment: Fortunately I figured out the same and its working. Can you please tell me how to hide export button when small chart is enabled?